# Accessing object with string creates TS Error : element implicitly has an any type because expression of type string can't be used to index type

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular and Typescript.I have an object that contains many properties: This object values are controlled by a form. The form contains many fields such as a form upload a text input etc...
Since, I have many form uploads. I wanted to make a function that would run on each and every form upload field else I'd have to write a function for each and every file upload. Basically, the function has this signature `function fileUpload (file : File,field : string)` assuming that the file is the File I'm trying to pass to the object and field is the field of the object.
I was trying to implement that function and TypeScript started giving some errors regarding the object and the field.

This is the code of the Angular component. The fileUpload function is defined below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChatWidgetSettings } from './models/chat-widget-settings';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-widget-chat',
  templateUrl: './widget-chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./widget-chat.component.scss']
})
export class WidgetChatComponent {
 settings : ChatWidgetSettings = {
    botActivation : false,
    chatButtonColor : '#34C4FC',
    closeIconColor : '#FFFFFF',
    launcherImage : null,
    profileClientAvatar:null,
    profileAvatar:null,
    titleAvatar:null,
    title : 'TestA',
    subtitle : 'TestB',
    titleFontColor : '#FFFFFF',
    subtitleFontColor : '#FFFFFF',
    titleBoxBackgroundColor : '#00687B',
    chatBoxBackgroundColor : '#FFFFFF',
    userMessageColor : "#00ACC7",
    botMessageColor : '#F4F7F9',
    userMessageFontColor : '#FFFFFF',
    responseMessageFontColor : '#000000',
    inputBoxBackgroundColor : '#00ACC7',
    inputBoxFontColor : '#000000',
    inputBoxPlaceholderFontColor : '#B4B4B4',
    inputBoxSendIconFontColor : '#4B4B4B',
    botMessageBorderColor:"#00ACC7",
    launcherImageURL:'',
    titleAvatarURL:'',
    profileClientAvatarURL:'',
    profileAvatarURL:'',
    showAvatar:false,
    
  };
  uploadFile(item : {
    field : string,
    file : File,
  }){
    // null fields in the object settings are the ones that would get the file object.
    //Error is generated on this level : element implicitly has an any 
    //type because expression of type string can't be used to index type
    this.settings[item.field] = file;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is going to undermine the type system when we set an object's field using its name. We will need to do a lot of complex things to make sure that the target field is of the correct type before trying to assign value.

A better approach would be to leverage the type system by creating a contract. We can achieve that by enforcing that each object must have a `file` property of type `File` if they want to use the `uploadFile` function.

```js
type FileViewModel = {
  file: File;
};

type ChatWidgetSettings = {
    name: string;
};

//Intersect ChatWidgetSettings with FileViewModel so it has file property.
type ChatWidgetSettingsViewModel = ChatWidgetSettings & FileViewModel;

function uploadFile<T extends FileViewModel>(setting: T, fileToUpload: File) {
    setting.file = fileToUpload;
}

const newFile = new File([], 'pdf');

const settings: ChatWidgetSettingsViewModel = {
    name: 'Widget',
    file: newFile
};

// call the function
uploadFile(settings, newFile);
```

Most people will complain that it is a lot of work to have each of the objects joins the contract. It would be easier and faster to access the field using its name and set the value.

I agree that it's a lot of work upfront, but the long-term benefit of type system will always outweigh the drawback of the fews extra keystrokes.

Comment: I mean I already did that, but If you're trying to affect a file into the this._setting[item.field] it wont really work, you'll get an error.

Comment: @Ghost What error did you get after you update your code to use `keyof`?

Comment: I created an interface that is like this:
`export interface
 FileUpload{
    file : File,
    field : keyof ChatWidgetSettings
}`
and then I tried creating an uploadFile method
`uploadFile(item : FileUpload){
    this.settings[item.field] = item.file;
  }`
I'd get this error then : `Type 'File' is not assignable to type 'never' `

Comment: @Ghost I updated the answer since the initial approach wasn't good. This new approach is better because we can now leverage the type system, and get any errors during compile-time.